# How to change positions of icons on Xamarin Shell tab bar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.shell

I'm using Shell on a Xamarin Forms app and the icons that I'm using on the `TabBar` are a little bit too high up
[image]
I would like to change their positions to the center but I can't find a way how.
How would I change the positions/alignment of the icons?
**TabPage xaml**

```
<!--TabBar Styles and Resources-->
    <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="FreeStyle" TargetType="Element">
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="#f7f7f7" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#999999"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="#61c9f7"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>


    <!--BluePill Pages-->
    <TabBar Style="{StaticResource FreeStyle}">
        <!--TeleMED Tab-->
        <Tab Icon="telemedicineIcon.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:TelemedicineMainPage}"/>
        </Tab>

        <!--Fleming Tab-->
        <Tab Icon="chatbotIcon.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ChatbotPage}"/>
        </Tab>

        <!--FirstAid Tab-->
        <Tab Icon="firstaidIcon.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:FirstAidPage}"/>
        </Tab>

        <!--User Profile Tab-->
        <Tab Icon="profileIcon.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:UserProfilePage}"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
```

Comment: ,If you want to change position of icons on xamarin shell tab bar, I search one article, may be helpful for you.https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/xamarin-forms-shell-customizing-the-tabbar-android

Comment: Yes, someone also referred me to that blog post, but I didn't find any iOS implementation and the whole guide seemed kinda convoluted.

Comment: It seems that you ask the same thread at https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/174859/how-to-change-the-size-and-position-of-icons-in-xamarin-shell-tabbar